# if attr url is not equal to a url redirect it

Tags: javascript, jquery

and really don't know much about jquery and I am already practicing, had some issue.

Question is that I have a url in the footer and I want if the url is not equal to *hariskhan.com.pk* then redirect it to *something.com*.

check my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   var check = $("a").attr('href');
   var haris = "http://www.hariskhan.com.pk";
   if (check == $("haris")) {
       $("body").css("background", "green");
   } 
   else {
       $("body").css("background", "orange");
   }
});
```

DOM:

```
<div class="footer"><a href="http://hariskhan.com.pk"/>
```

Comment: body style was just for practice so i don't know the redirect location as well . please answer someone .

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect it to something.com"? Do you want to change the link's href? And the comparison should be `if (check == haris) { ... }`

Comment: i mean if someone change the footer  href then it should redirect it to my specific url

Comment: So when the page loads, you want to scan its contents and check a link's href? If the href doesn't match your test you want to redirect to _something.com_?

Comment: yes this is my exactly question

Comment: thankew for understanding

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a string to a jQuery object. So let's fix that first

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   var check = $("a").attr('href');
   var haris = "http://www.hariskhan.com.pk";
   if (check == haris) {
       ...
   }
});
```

Then you want to redirect the page

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   var check = $("a").attr('href');
   var haris = "http://www.hariskhan.com.pk";
   if (check == haris) {
       location.href = "//something.com";
   } 
   else {
       $("body").css("background", "orange");
   }
});
```

Comment: This is the way ;)

Answer (score 0):

well, first let's start by asking did you put the jquery code in a script tag??
did you create a proper html dom?
do you understand that you jquery code needs to select href from a  tag?
you need to study html and understand a bit about how it integrates to javascripts before you start jquery

Comment: i know that , i have put jquery in script and everything is loading perfectly jqeury min also mean jquery is working fine .

Comment: check should contain all a tags from your dom, not just one, did you check it in the console??